# Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer ro a managed type

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm trying to implement a double linked list in c# but I've never used pointers before and cannot find a solution.
I'm trying to create the node class which will hold a single item and pointers to the adjacent nodes.

```
// single elements in the list 
unsafe class Node { Node* previous}
{
    public int data;
    public Node *next;
    public Node *prev = *previous;
}
```

I keep getting the error in the title and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You don't need a pointer, you just need a reference to the next/previous nodes. I doubt the intent of your exercise was to use `unsafe` code with pointers.

Comment: Recently Pluralsight prompted me to do a C# skill evaluation. Two of the first five questions were about `unsafe` and pointers. I thought that was really odd because - not that I'm advocating not knowing things - I never, ever, ever use that stuff and I suspect that many of us could go on forever without encountering it, except maybe `unsafe` in ReSharper-generated `GetHashCode` overrrides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need unasnaged pointers or `unsafe` here at all. Because `Node` is a class, when you use `Node` as a parameter, field, variable etc - this is a *reference* to a `Node` instance. A *reference* here means "managed pointer" - i.e. like a pointer, but with full GC support and type safety, etc. So all you need is `Node`:

```cs
class Node
{
    public int Data {get;set;}
    public Node Next {get;set;}     // Next/Previous might want "private set" if
    public Node Previous {get;set;} // you are going to change them via methods
}
```

More specifically, you *cannot* readily take an *unmanaged* pointer to a `class` in C# - a `Node*` - that simply *isn't a thing you can do*. You can do that with `struct`, but: you almost certainly *shouldn't*. I expect the point here is to use *managed* pointers, aka references, i.e. `Node`, not `Node*`.

Answer (score 0):

As CrowCoder stated you do not and should not use pointers in C# for this implementation. This code should get you started:

```
internal class LLNode {  
    internal int data;  
    internal LLNode prev;  
    internal LLNode next;  
    public LLNode (int d) {  
        data = d;  
        prev = null;  
        next = null;  
    }  
}
```